# How to check if string is equal to any of multiple strings objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have 5 NSStrings, and I want to see if any of the strings are the same, is there a faster way than using `[string isEqualToString:string2]` a bunch of times to test each string?

Comment: Faster as in less typing or less computing?

Comment: I dont mind the typing, I am talking about less computing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only 5 strings, probably nothing will be faster than comparing one by one.

But if you have many strings, create an NSSet with all of them, then just check whether the string is a member of that set, by using `-[containsObject:]`.

Comment: +1 for a good approach, but it's worth noting that NSSet's `-containsObject:` probably uses `-isEqual:`. The NSString docs say that if you know both objects are strings, `-isEqualToString:` is faster than `-isEqual:`, so `-containsObject:` probably isn't faster after all.

Comment: -containsObject: is one -hash if the string isn't there, or one -hash and one -isEqual: if the string is there. Calling -isEqualToString: on each string is 1-N calls, averaging N/2. So, unless the string length is on the same order as N (hence the "if you only have 5 strings" bit), there's no comparison—it's a constant algorithm vs. a linear one.

Comment: I have created a NSSet of all my strings. Is there a way to tell if there are duplicates? Also is it possible to tell which entries in the NSSet are duplicates? Thanks

Comment: There are never any duplicates in a set. Look at the documentation for methods like +setWithObjects: (and also things like -[NSMutableSet addObject:]) and they explain exactly what happens when you try to put duplicates in a set. If you need to know that you have multiple copies of the same value, usually the best answer is to use NSCountedSet (which keeps track of how many times each element has been added).